# Java references. Does Java make a special check with string literals?

Tags: java, reference

```
public class Test {
    int multiple;
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String string1 = "string";
        String string2 = "string";
        String string4 = "Changed";

        String string3 = new String("string");

        System.out.println("string1 == string2: " + (string1 == string2));\\true
        System.out.println("string1 == string4: " + (string1 == string4));\\false
        System.out.println("string1 == string3: " + (string1 == string3));\\false

    }


}
```

I understand that the `==` operator will return `true` if the references are same. What I want to know is, Does Java check the content of string literals before creating their objects?

Comment: Yes, in a way. There is the String pool that holds Strings that allows for re-use, but it's not perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the compiler that does the string interning. So at compile time identical strings are optimised. So I think the answer you want is "no". The Virtual Machine doesn't do it, it is the compiler. You can call [`String.intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) to acquire the shared string object in the string pool:

```
String str1 = "string";
String str2 = new String("string");
String str3 = str2.intern();

str1 == str2 // false
str2 == str3 // false
str1 == str3 // true
```

Strings, build at runtime are not interned automatically.

Comment: Is it right to say that `intern()` basically checks whether the content is same or not

Comment: No, it checks if it has that string on which you call the method, is already in the string pool. If so, it returns the reference from the pool. If not, it creates a new string in the pool and returns that reference.

Comment: Yes, it is content based. But, I think it uses hashCodes, to optimise.

Comment: [`String.intern()` is a native function (in OpenJDK, at least)](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html#3071); consequently, I doubt it uses `hashCode()`. I recall seeing a version of `java.lang.String` which was not native, but delegated to the native `VM.intern()` method, though of course I can't dig it up now...

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing one of the side effects of [Java string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). From [the JLS §3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> ...A string literal always refers to the *same* instance of class `String`. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions ([§15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

[Lots more reading on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20string%20intern), especially:

- [If == compares references in Java, why does it evaluate to true with these Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033625/if-compares-references-in-java-why-does-it-evaluate-to-true-with-these-strin)
- [Java string intern and literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777131/java-string-intern-and-literal)
- [When is it beneficial to flyweight Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972841/when-is-it-beneficial-to-flyweight-strings-in-java)
- [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: It's worth noting here that the JLS appears to be incorrect. The compiler can't use String.intern() for this purpose, as the process described happens at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: @EJP what you say doesn't really make sense. Where does the JLS say anything about interning happening at compile time (viz. _"the compiler can't use String.intern() for this purpose"_)? The constant expressions are _identified_ at compile time, and the `String#intern()` call is inserted by the compiler, but the method isn't actually _called_ until runtime. Heck, the intern pool doesn't exist until runtime. Correct me if I've misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Erm, where does it say anything about the compiler or compile time?

Comment: It's talking about string literals and constant-valued string expressions. Only the compiler can even see either of those. To the JVM they are all just String objects.